# How do I increase password strength in Djano through adding rules?

Tags: django, django-registration

How do I specify rules for passwords in a [django-registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html#registration.forms.RegistrationForm) v1.0 installation?

I would like to enforce the following:

1. A minimum length for passwords
2. Require password to contain at least 1 uppercase
3. Require password to contain at least 1 lowercase
4. Require a mix of letters and numbers

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check with python before you save the password.

```
upper_case = sum(1 for c in password if c.isupper())
digits = sum(1 for c in password if c.isdigit())
length = len(password)
```

That will return numeric values of how many characters are uppercase and how many digits, and the length of the password submitted, you will then have to implement a way to use them correctly

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The idea is to overwrite the build-in password1 field that comes with the django-registration. just don't know how to do that. Any thought?